# Where should I ask a question involving rsync, Mac, and NTFS?

Tags: support

rsync is more of a Linux thing, but I'm using it to update NTFS from a Mac.  I went through the list and didn't see a Windows community (but could have missed it).

In case it matters, here's the question:
Why does rsync update NTFS directories when the source has not changed?

I'm taking classes with lots of phonetic and grammatical analysis.  They've given me an account on a Windows 10 network.  Since I am much more comfortable with Mac and Linux (and since the Windows availability hours are limited), I do my work on my Mac laptop.  I automounted my NTFS directories, but there's something flaky with their LAN, so that quite often **some** apps have read-only access or no access at all.  Consequently, I work in a local copy and frequently rsync changes.  But rsync **always** updates **every** NTFS directory—the directory only, never any files (unless I have actually changed the file).  Most of those directories, I have never navigated into, yet rsync reports updates all the way down the subduer tree.  It's not major—finishes in seconds—but it's still pretty weird.

Comment: [su] is the Windows community if there's one. It accepts everything, so if it's a truly cross-platform issue, then it would be the best place. But if you can't touch the Windows server, and you can only deal with the Mac, and that can belong here or on [apple.se].